# ListView changes the word value at every restart of program

Tags: c#, listview

I have a program which I can type in some Informations about peoples. For Example:

```
Surname: Tomson
Forename: Tyler
```

Then I hit the "Add" button and it adds me the new person to the `listView`. If I restart the program now, the names are changed. So there must be "Tomson Tyler" but there is "Tyler Tomson". If I restart it again, it changes the names again. So every restart the word changes. I don't know why. Here is my code to add a people to the `listView`:

```
List<People> people = new List<People>();

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        if (!File.Exists(path + "\\save.xml"))
        {
            XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter(path + "\\save.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.Close();
        }

        People p = new People();
        p.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
        p.Forename = txtForename.Text;

        people.Add(p);
        listViewKunden.Items.Add(p.Surname + " " + p.Forename);

        txtSurname.Text = "";
        txtForename.Text = "";
}

class People
{
    public string Surname
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Forename
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to share the code for loading and saving the `xml` file. Here it is. First part for loading/reading and second part for saving:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xdocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xdocument.Load(path + "\\save.xml");
    foreach (XmlNode xnode in xdocument.SelectNodes("Root/People"))
    {
        People p = new People();
        p.Nachname = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Surname").InnerText;
        p.Vorname = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Forename").InnerText;

        people.Add(p);
        listViewKunden.Items.Add(p.Surname + " " + p.Forename);
    }

    using (FileStream rfs = new FileStream(path + "\\save.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(rfs);
    }
}


private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml("<Root></Root>");
    XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Root");
    using(FileStream wfs = new FileStream(path + "\\NewFred.xml",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
       doc.Save(wfs);
    }
    foreach (People p in people)
    {
        XmlNode xtop = xdoc.CreateElement("People");
        XmlNode xsurname = xdoc.CreateElement("Surname");
        XmlNode xvorname = xdoc.CreateElement("Forename");

        xsurname.InnerText = p.Forename;
        xforename.InnerText = p.Surname;

        xtop.AppendChild(xsurname);
        xtop.AppendChild(xforename);

        xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xtop);
    }
    xdoc.Save(path + "\\save.xml");
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that *actually saves* the XML file? And what about the code that *reads* it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I will add it in an edit :)

Comment: xsurname.InnerText = p.Forename;
 xforename.InnerText = p.Surname;

Comment: Hi, what application it is?  Windows/WPF/Asp.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have these switched:

```
xsurname.InnerText = p.Forename;
xforename.InnerText = p.Surname;
```

they should be:

```
xsurname.InnerText = p.Surname;
xforename.InnerText = p.Forename;
```

Comment: Omg. I didn't see that all the time >.< What a mistake... Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Firms must read about XML serialization and deserialization.
Second mising attributes in your properties and class model.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
 using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, writerSettings))
 {
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
 }


var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);


[Serializable]
public class Settings


public class TaxRates
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxRate")]
    public decimal ReturnTaxRate;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but this is a complete other way, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
xsurname.InnerText = p.Forename;
        xforename.InnerText = p.Surname;
```

other posible reson is not corredctly sorting if problem is depending with wrong locating row.

before close you must sort. may be this is your problem. after every save/close you change orders of rows. Check this.

Comment: -1: This answer could be an edit or an addition to your first answer but not a single answer.